# How to add to the content of a div without deleting it's original content using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was making a quiz site and when I came to the point when I was making a button to show you the correct answer of your mistake I used document.getElementById but it always erased the rest of the answers that was written by the same method.

here is a snippet of my javascript code

```
if (mistakes > 0) {
  if (document.getElementById('wrongAnswer1').checked === true || 
      document.getElementById('wrongAnswer2').checked === true) {
        document.getElementById('mistakesDiv').innerHTML =
          document.getElementById('mistakesDiv').innerHTML + 
          "<br>" + 
          "question 1's correct answer is" + 
          document.getElementById('correctAnswer1').value;
   }
}
```

Comment: what does your HTML look like. And how is `mistakesDiv` being populated in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your `html div` as:

```
<div id="contentId">
 ......
 ......
</div>
```

And your javascript like:

```
var div = document.getElementById('contentId');
div.innerHTML += 'your content';
```

Comment: No, it resets any value already charged if it is a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the content which you are adding dynamically from existing content because when you are updating innerHTML it will update all the content inside the selected element.
So one solution is take a parent div(the div which you will select for adding new child) and add child divs(dynamically added div) inside that for each correct answer.
If you want to give some id to dynamic div you can use a counter or question id for which this new child div has got added.
For adding new children to "parent" you can use "appendChild" method.
It will be something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">Here goes the correct answer</div>(button element will also work fine)
</div>
```

I have created a fiddle for your scenario please have a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/jbw7ku15/

Answer (score 0):

In order to append without changing the actual html, for example you want to give the user the ability to add fields to a form that he is in process of filling. You can use insertAdjacentHTML

```
var html = "<br>" + "question 1's correct answer is" + document.getElementById('correctAnswer1').value;
document.getElementById('mistakesDiv').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing just `node += template` will work if you don't work with forms, but if you do, there is a great chance that form data will be deleted when this line executed. It's pretty simple actually, you just can do:

```js
const WRAPPER = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const NODE = document.createElement('div');
const NODE_TEMPLATE = `<div>hello world</div>`;
NODE.innerHTML = NODE_TEMPLATE;
WRAPPER.appendChild(NODE);
```

this prevents any content deletions, and it's convenient.